# How to put selected options of a mutliple select in first position

Tags: javascript, angular, html

I have a select tag with multiple options and when the page is loaded I would like to put the selected options in first positions in the list. I'm using angular so my code for the select is :

```
<select class="form-control" id="field_shopName" multiple name="shopName [(ngModel)]=" product.shopNames ">
    <option [ngValue]="getSelected(product.shopNames, shopPdvOption) " *ngFor="let shopPdvOption of shoppdvs; trackBy: trackShopPdvById ">{{shopPdvOption.shopPdV}}</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to acheive this with only html5 or javascript ?

Comment: do you have an Angular Component behind that html? if so, could you add it to the question?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. The example below will add an extra list of fruits first.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var select = document.getElementById("fruits");
    var firstFruits = ['Kiwi', 'Peach', 'Orange'].reverse();
    
    firstFruits.forEach(function (fruit) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = option.value = fruit;
      select.add(option, 0);
    })
};
```

```html
<select id="fruits">
  <option>Apple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How to implement that into angular app ?

Comment: Add it as a method for the component and then call it in `ngOnInit`.

Comment: The right way would be to use @ViewChild to get the select tag reference, instead of `document.getElementById`. However, that's a different question. :)

Comment: Not sure this is a different question. The OP is tagged angular. You reply for a vanillaJS way.

Comment: The question code snippet was in Angular, however, the question was: `Is it possible to achieve this with only html5 or javascript?` If there's something else I can help, I'm glad to.